# Why I got this error: "SQL Error 1025: Error on rename of '...' to '...' (errno: 150)"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1025

I want to rename a field of a table in MySQL ver 5.2.25, from "alter table", but I got this error:

```
SQL Error 1025: Error on rename of '.\Packers\#sql-804_3' to '.\Packers\pattern' (errno: 150)
```

but on other table I had not this problem, I don't know why, is it caused by foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a foreign key error. Do `show innodb status` immediately after your `alter table` attempt, and part of the output will be the last foreign key error details.

Generally it's caused by a data type mismatch on the foreign key fields (it's 'int' in one table but 'bigint' in your alter table, or one's unsigned and the other's not, etc...)

Comment: Hi, Error is not caused by data type, this is the result of "show innodb status":
=====================================
101030 13:50:43 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 45 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 4, signal coun...

Comment: The status output is way too big to paste into a comment. edit your question and paste it there.